# Oracle : merging a row and its next one into the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have an issue here.

I have these `4 rows` of data :

**Origin Destination Distance Carrier Price**

```
Miami New-York     800      BF      500

Dallas Chicago     300      AL      200

Dallas Chicago     300      KH      200

Miami New-York     800      JH      500
```

What i want is to merge rows 2 and 3 into one row like this :

`Dallas Chicago 300 AL, KH 200` (All information is the same except the Carrier)

The problem is that I have to check if the previous row is containing the same information except carriers, for all rows.

How can I achieve that ? with `LEAD` and `LAG` ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: But why aren't the Miami  New-York  flights merged too?

Comment: Because we want to merge only rows with the directly following one (if it's the same flight with same information except carrier)

Comment: You have to add another column with order info in that case. (A table's rows are unordered.)

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join:

```
select t1.Origin, t1.Destination, t1.Distance, t1.Carrier, t2.Distance, t2.Carrier
from table t1
  join table t2 on  t1.Origin = t2.Origin
                and t1.Destination = t2.Destination
                and t1.Carrier < t2.Carrier
```

Row order unimportant here. (Of course, that's the dbms way!)

If you want to return alone flights too, do `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.

Comment: but if he has 3 rows to merge?

Comment: Mmm, I think we must give to our friend, a general solution. He can't change the query every time a new row must be merged

Comment: That would of course be much better. But I'm not sure OP really knows what he wants...

Comment: Yep, I'm thinking to create a PL/SQL function or procedure in order to do this, but the issue is that this is must be included in the VIEW creation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. But it will add Miami New-York row too. If you want only 2 adjecent rows to be merged, then you need another column like ID or InsertDate or something like that. Then we can modify the given query to aggregate based on that.

```
              with tbl  (Origin, Destination, Distance ,Carrier ,Price)
              as
              (select 'Miami','New-York',800,'BF ', 500 from dual union
              select 'Dallas','Chicago',300,' AL', 200 from dual union
              select 'Dallas','Chicago',300,' KH', 200 from dual union
              select 'Miami','New-York',800,'JH',500 from dual)

              select Origin,Destination,Distance,listagg(carrier,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY origin ) as AggCarrier,Price from tbl
              group by  Origin,Destination,Distance,Price
```

Output

```
      Origin  Destination Distance AggCarrier Price                 
      Miami     New-York    800     BF ,JH     500
      Dallas    Chicago     300     AL, KH     200
```

EDIT: Unless we have any column to identify the insert order of the data, you cannot achieve what you want. See the below example. I tried addidng rownum to your data. But it will not assign the rownum in the way you want exactly. It has to come from the table which you want to use. See the example below.

```
          with tbl  (Origin, Destination, Distance ,Carrier ,Price)
          as
          (select 'Miami','New-York',800,'BF', 500 from dual union
          select 'Dallas','Chicago',300,'AL', 200 from dual union
          select 'Dallas','Chicago',300,'KH', 200 from dual union
          select 'Miami','New-York',800,'JH',500 from dual
          )
          select rownum,tbl.* from tbl
```

The Output doestn't return Miami first row before Dallas.

```
      ROWNUM ORIGIN DESTINATION DISTANCE CARRIER PRICE             
      1      Dallas Chicago     300      AL      200
      2      Dallas Chicago     300      KH      200
      3      Miami  New-York    800      BF      500
      4      Miami  New-York    800      JH      500
```

So you need anything. ID/InsertTime or any other identifier to find that. Else DB will never know which record was inserted first. Please ask for it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not aware of what data is stored exactly on DB. I just gave an example, and in Db there is millions of rows. I'm looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: Added explanation to why you need an indentifier.

Comment: Thanks Utsav, I think your idea is good, I'll add an ID to each view row. So if I had an ID, the rownum will aggregate adjacent rows ?

Comment: No. This query will still aggregate all rows. We have to modify our query and 
 - Compare if the origin / destination / Distance / Price is same as previous row.
 - If yes that aggregate it.

It would be bit tricky to implement it. Please confirm if you have ID or InsertTime as identifier and we can work from there. In the meantime try adding lead/lag to compare rows and see if you can come up with something.

Comment: Yes, this is a view so we can add an ID as long as we want.

Comment: Precision : I'm under Oracle 10, so the LISTAGG function is not supported.

Comment: In that case do something like below
 1) generate ID
 2) Add couple of other another column in CTE table for flagging.
 3) Use lead/lag fucntions to capture previous rows data in current row
 4) Compare orgin/desn (etc) for previous row. If same, then concatenate carrier.
  5) Set different flag values if prev/curr rows are same. 
  6) Now you would have same number of rows and in some of them the carrier will be concatenated.
 7) Later add another CTE and add a flag to rows you want to see in output.
  8) select only flagged rows

I can try this tomorrow and update